# Gutenberg pass properties to filter

Tags: block-editor

I'm using [Gutenberg block filters](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock) to add a class name to the block’s wrapper component in the editor.

```
registerBlockType( name, {

    title: __( 'My Block' ),

    parent: [ 'myplugin/myblock' ],

    category: 'common',

    attributes: attributes,


    edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {      

        const { someName } = attributes;

        return (
            /* render something */
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {

        const { someName } = attributes;

        return (
            /* render something */
        );
    },
});



const customClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ someName } />;
    };
}, 'customClassName' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'myplugin/myblock', customClassName );
```

How can I pass `someName` from my block attributes to the `customClassName` filter? Adding constant `customClassName` and `wp.hooks.addFilter()` in the edit function does not seem to work well because it causes repeatable filtering/rendering.

Comment: You want to add a class in the (default) className attribute that includes some value from your own attribute?

Comment: Yes it will include some dynamic value